# Viewing database from db files [BerkeleyDB]

Tags: java, ubuntu-14.04, berkeley-db, ifc

I am playing with an open source project [Bim Server](http://bimserver.org/) and I checked out the code from [git](https://github.com/opensourceBIM/BIMserver/wiki). When Bim server is started it creates `home/database` folder and inside database folder following files available,

```
lp:/media/isuru/Projects/bimServer/home/database$ ll 
total 672 
drwx------ 1 isuru isuru   4096 අප්‍රි  17 18:06 ./ 
drwx------ 1 isuru isuru   4096 අප්‍රි  17 18:06 ../
-rw------- 1 isuru isuru 641810 අප්‍රි  17 18:54 00000000.jdb
-rw------- 2 isuru isuru   6079 අප්‍රි  17 18:02 je.config.csv
-rw------- 2 isuru isuru      0 අප්‍රි  17 18:02 je.info.0
-rw------- 2 isuru isuru      0 අප්‍රි  17 18:06 je.info.0.lck
-rw------- 1 isuru isuru      0 අප්‍රි  17 18:02 je.lck
-rw------- 2 isuru isuru  28527 අප්‍රි  17 18:54 je.stat.csv
```

Now what I'm trying to see, how the data are stored in this berkeley db. Is there tools for this?

And I could find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786800/how-to-connect-to-a-berkeley-db-using-jdbc) on `stack overlfow` but its not answered as well.

Comment: You will need to learn to query BerkeleyDB and here is a [link to the official Oracle documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/seltzer-berkeleydb-sql-086752.html).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks for the quick reply, I haven't installed berkeley db. What I have is only the files created by `Bim Server` application. I want to analyze the created tables by the Bim Server, by inspecting the files created. So what I am asking is, is it possible? then how? using what (tools I mean)? [sorry for the bad english]

Comment: for reference: http://blog.cppcms.com/post/5 this blog post says what berkeleydb is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BerkeleyDB is an embedded key-value store.  It runs inside the application that uses it.  On disk, the records may be stored in a binary form that typically makes sense only to the application.

Usually (but not always, I grant) this means that the best way to query an application's data that's stored in BerkeleyDB is to use that application to query the data.  Frequently there are diagnostic commands specific to each application to enable this.

You can experiment with the db_dump command-line utility, but unless you're quite lucky, the output is likely to be meaningless.